# How to Absorb a Keypress?

Tags: ms-access, vba, keypress

On my form I have an edit control.  I have set up a `KeyDown` event to detect when the user pushes <kbd>enter</kbd>, but I also want to detect <kbd>shift+space</kbd> so the user can clear the contents of the box.

The functionality works - I can detect the keypress.  Problem is that the <kbd>space</kbd> does not get absorbed and so the space glyph is still typed in the control.

How can I absorb the keypress when I push <kbd>shift+space</kbd>?

```
Private Sub FindBox_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyEnter: SearchForIt
        Case vbKeySpace:
            If Shift = 1 Then
                FindBox.Text = ""
                'here absorb keypress instead of sending space to control
                Exit Sub
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the value of KeyCode = 0. That will "swallow" the key and not have anything happen.

You also want to use the bit mask to look for the presence of the shift being pressed

```
Dim intShiftDown As Integer
intShiftDown = (Shift And acShiftMask) > 0 

    Case vbKeySpace:
        If intShiftDown Then
            FindBox.Text = ""
            'here absorb keypress instead of sending space to control
            KeyCode = 0
            Exit Sub
```

Comment: Haha - I beat you to the punch!  But I hate to accept my own answers, so once the time limit passes, I'll accept yours.  Thanks for answering!

Comment: When I started typing in the answer, you hadn't yet replied! I saw your comment as soon as mine posted. I'm new, so it was taking me too long to get the formatting correct for the block (wound up doing the spaces, rather than a surrounding `. Still trying to get used to the formatting options for good looking answers. At least I added some value with the bit mask! :)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I figured it out.
It was simple.

```
'here absorb keypress instead of sending space to control
KeyCode = 0
```