# How to Intercept built-in Find Procedure?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my Access project I have a custom find procedure.

Now I want to eradicate the built-in Find procedure so the user doesn't try to use that.

So I have two tasks to acccomplish:

1. Intercept the <kbd>ctrl+F</kbd> hotkey
2. Remove the Find button from the ribbon.

On my main form I have *Key Preview* enabled, and I know how to [detect keypresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279201/how-to-absorb-a-keypress/31279270#31279270), but I'm not sure how to detect the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key.

Now what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `Shift = 2`. The Shift value will be 1 if Shift is pressed, 2 if Ctrl is pressed, 4 if Alt is pressed, the sum of those values if two or three of those Buttons are pressed or 0 if None of them is pressed. So your `If` Statement should look like this:

```
If KeyCode = vbKeyF and Shift = 2 then
    KeyCode = 0
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) everywhere in your entire database you can do the following:

Create a macro called "AutoKeys"

Once you have created this macro, double-click "Submacro" under Action Catalog

Name that Submacro "^F"

Leave the action empty

Basically this should prevent (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) from working on any form in your database.  Additionally you should be able to create other Submacros for other key combinations you wish to control.

I have never used this before myself and just tested it briefly and it worked fine.  Though I can neither condone nor condemn it with regards to long term usage.

**Note:** This was tested in MS Access 2010 so you may have to adjust for your version.

Comment: Thanks for that; I didn't realize that `shift` meant more than *shift*.  No clue about the ribbon find button?

Comment: @BGM Unless they have Office Pro, I don't believe they have access to that.

Comment: Our entire office has Office Pro.  I have to figure something out because if they use it it will cause the application to hang.

Comment: @BGM I know how to entirely hide the ribbon from users, does that work for your situation?

Comment: Newd - No, I'm not ready to hide the ribbon completely.  Sorry to make a two-part question, but it's all closely related, and sometimes there's a lower level answer that satisfies both parts... If I can interecept the button's functionality then I would not have to remove it.

Comment: @BGM In that cause I am almost positive you are going to need to explore the custom ribbon path.  Unfortunately I don't have enough experience with it that I can be of much use.  I had dabbled, but not enough to pass on that knowledge.